# How to unmarshall / store unknown json fields?

Tags: json, go

I need to Unmarshal json from a 3rd party API. Although I know the response type I need to make sure I don't loose any field that the API may introduce (the api has no documentation) so I'm wondering how can I do that. Ideally I would like to store the unknown fields in an interface{} value and perhaps encode it for later audit. Here is what i've tried so far but it doesn't work(`Data` field which is "unknown" at compile time is lost during unmarshalling).

[Play](http://play.golang.org/p/PqFATdMpiS)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Tweet struct {
    User_id int
    Message string
    Unknown
}
type Unknown map[interface{}]interface{}

func main() {
    // Define an empty interface
    var t Tweet

    // Convert JSON string into bytes
    b := []byte(`{"user_id": 1, "message": "Hello world", "Date": "somerandom date"}`)

    // Decode bytes b into interface i
    json.Unmarshal(b, &t)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Comment: may  load data in map[string]interface{}, and then compare with the known fields?

Comment: That sounds quite laborious isn't it? I mean if you have nested fields and many types to unmarshall.

Comment: I don't know. This is the only solution that I can offer.

Comment: What do you need the unknown part for? [`RawMessage`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) might be of help to you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The point is that I should store the "unknown" fields in a blob or something so that i can audit them later and change the types accordingly. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could use RawMessage as inf suggested. Here's an example using [sharktanklabs j2n package](https://github.com/sharktanklabs/j2n).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/sharktanklabs/j2n"
)

type TweetData struct {
    User_id  int
    Message  string
    Overflow map[string]*json.RawMessage `json:"-"`
}

type Tweet struct {
    TweetData
}

func (c *Tweet) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    return j2n.UnmarshalJSON(data, &c.TweetData)
}

func (c Tweet) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return j2n.MarshalJSON(c.TweetData)
}

func main() {
    // Define an empty interface
    var t Tweet

    // Convert JSON string into bytes
    b := []byte(`{"user_id": 1, "message": "Hello world", "Date": "somerandom date"}`)

    // Decode bytes b into interface i
    json.Unmarshal(b, &t)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", t)
}
// Formatted output: 
//     main.Tweet{TweetData:main.TweetData{
//         User_id:1, 
//         Message:"Hello world",     
//         Overflow:map[string]*json.RawMessage{
//             "user_id":(*json.RawMessage)(0xc82000e340), 
//             "message":(*json.RawMessage)(0xc82000e3c0), 
//             "Date":(*json.RawMessage)(0xc82000e440)}}}
```